# How to change page culture using dropdownbox in login page?

Tags: asp.net, culture

I want to change lang in login and refresh page but in my combobox is null in InitialCulture function.

Code Behind :

```
protected void myLang_OnChange(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        InitializeCulture();
    }

    protected override void InitializeCulture()
    {
        string Kultur = myLang.SelectedValue;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Kultur)) Kultur = "Auto";

        this.UICulture = Kultur;
        this.Culture = Kultur;


        base.InitializeCulture();
    }
```

aspx :

```
  <asp:DropDownList Name="myLang" ID="myLang" runat="server" 
                OnSelectedIndexChanged="myLang_OnChange" AutoPostBack="True">
                <asp:ListItem Text="Auto" Value="auto" />
                <asp:ListItem Text="Türkçe" Value="tr-TR" />
                <asp:ListItem Text="İngilizce" Value="en-US" />
  </asp:DropDownList>
```

thx for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't call the `InitializeCulture` method. You have to save `SelectedValue` of `DropDownList` to the `Session`.

```
protected void myLang_OnChange(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session["lang"]=myLang.SelectedValue;
        Response.Redirect("your_current_page.aspx");
    }

protected override void InitializeCulture()
  {
    string Kultur="en-US"; // default lang
   if(Session["lang"]!=null)
     Kultur = Session["lang"].ToString();

    this.UICulture = Kultur;
    this.Culture = Kultur;
    base.InitializeCulture();
 }
```

Comment: Also have i define initialCulture function all page ?

Comment: Yes! that is true. Have a look at - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tc508.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You have mismatch in your code

```
  string Kultur = myLang.SelectedValue;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Kultur)) Kultur = "Auto"; <--
```

you must replace with value tr-TR, because you get value